# Issue appending content to DOM with jQuery (only on Safari iOS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mobile-safari

After a successful AJAX request I append some HTML to the DOM using Jquery.

It works fine in all desktop browsers, Safari in the iPhone simulator and Chrome on my iPhone.

However when I test in Safari on my iPhone 5S in iOS 8, the content is sometimes appended and sometimes no content is appended at all.

I was hoping that using the iPhone simulator would reveal the issue using Developer Tools in Safari, however it does not replicate the issue.

I have considered the length of the JSON response in the AJAX request but it is not very long and the issue still occurs. I have also validated it and it seems fine.

Relevant part of JS:

```
$tpl == 'some html content';
var $node = $($tpl);
$node.data({
    'event_id': event.event_id,
    'event_story_id': (event[0] !== undefined) ? event[0].event_story_id : 0,
    'date': event.datetotime
});
$node.find('time').each(function(i, e) {
    var time = moment(event.event_date_utc);
    $(e).html(time.fromNow());
});
$($node).hide().appendTo('#timeline > ul').fadeIn(800);
```

JSON Response:

```
{"status":"success","message":"","comment_image":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/mfstb\/profile\/small\/70-507d37914cdaf.jpg","user":{"title":"Asa Carter's Life Stories","image":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/mfstb\/profile\/small\/70-507d37914cdaf.jpg"},"paging":{"total":46,"limit":3,"pages":16,"page":1,"prev_page":1,"next_page":2},"events":{"0":{"event_id":1373,"event_name":"fgdfgdfg","event_description":"","event_date":"25\/07\/14","event_date_utc":"2014-07-25T16:25:48+00:00","event_datetotime":1406305548,"story_count":{"total":1,"photo":1,"video":0,"audio":0},"owner":1,"comment_count":0,"number_of_comment":2,"stories":{"0":{"event_story_id":"2238","event_story_description":"","event_story_type":"photo","event_story_token":"53d285100e571","event_file_type":"jpg","event_file_url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/mfstb\/story\/photo\/full\/2238-53d285100e571.jpg","event_medium_url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/mfstb\/story\/photo\/large\/2238-53d285100e571.jpg","event_thumb_url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/mfstb\/story\/photo\/small\/2238-53d285100e571.jpg","event_comment":"","processed":"1"}}},"1":{"event_id":1368,"event_name":"Test MP4","event_description":"","event_date":"02\/06\/14","event_date_utc":"2014-06-02T10:21:09+00:00","event_datetotime":1401704469,"story_count":{"total":1,"photo":0,"video":1,"audio":0},"owner":1,"comment_count":0,"number_of_comment":0,"stories":{"0":{"event_story_id":"2230","event_story_description":"","event_story_type":"video","event_story_token":"538c420659e07","event_file_type":"m4v","event_file_url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/mfstb\/story\/video\/2230-538c420659e07.m4v","event_medium_url":"","event_thumb_url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/mfstb\/story\/photo\/small\/2230-538c420659e07.jpg","event_comment":"","processed":"1"}}},"2":{"event_id":1367,"event_name":"Testing 3gp video sample","event_description":"","event_date":"01\/06\/14","event_date_utc":"2014-06-01T21:54:22+00:00","event_datetotime":1401659662,"story_count":{"total":1,"photo":0,"video":1,"audio":0},"owner":1,"comment_count":0,"number_of_comment":0,"stories":{"0":{"event_story_id":"2229","event_story_description":"","event_story_type":"video","event_story_token":"538b92ffcf560","event_file_type":"m4v","event_file_url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/mfstb\/story\/video\/2229-538b92ffcf560.m4v","event_medium_url":"","event_thumb_url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/mfstb\/story\/photo\/small\/2229-538b92ffcf560.jpg","event_comment":"","processed":"1"}}}},"generated":0.1763}
```

Comment: have you wrapped this code inside `$(document).ready(function(){..});`

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Yes

Answer (score -3):

Use this JS code instead.

```
$tpl == 'some html content';
var $node = $($tpl);
event.preventDefault();
$node.data({
    'event_id': event.event_id,
    'event_story_id': (event[0] !== undefined) ? event[0].event_story_id : 0,
    'date': event.datetotime
});
$node.find('time').each(function(i, e) {
    var time = moment(event.event_date_utc);
    $(e).html(time.fromNow());
});
$($node).hide().appendTo('#timeline > ul').fadeIn(800);
```

Comment: What are you suggesting ? event.preventDefault()?

Comment: this is not a answer, sorry